# Django - Display a pandas dataframe into django template

Tags: python, django, pandas

everybody.

I'm trying to use Django to display a pandas dataframe example, but it doesn't render. I tried use for statement, the function `df.to_html`, with no success. I hope you help me, I would appreciate it.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Nome': ['Beatriz', 'Ana', 'Flávia', 'Bianca'],
         'Idade': [23, 24, 24, 19],
         'Profissao': ['Analista de Sistemas', 'Advogada', 'Promotora', 'Jornalista'],
         'Renda_mensal': [5000, 8000, 15000, 4500]
        })
    df = df.to_html()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Em construção</h1>

    {{ df }}
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you since now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use context:

views.py

```
def index(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Nome': ['Beatriz', 'Ana', 'Flávia', 'Bianca'],
         'Idade': [23, 24, 24, 19],
         'Profissao': ['Analista de Sistemas', 'Advogada', 'Promotora', 'Jornalista'],
         'Renda_mensal': [5000, 8000, 15000, 4500]
         })
    df = df.to_html()
    context = {'df': df}  # change
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)  # change
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Em construção</h1>

    {{ df|safe }}  <!-- change -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: df in template]

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Marcia. One curiosity: are you brazilian? I am haha. Could you tell me what is the use of context? Or a good reference about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes I am :) Sure! From the docs: "A template is rendered with a context. Rendering replaces variables with their values, which are looked up in the context, and executes tags" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#template-language-intro So every variable you want to use in the templates - using the tags {{ name_of_variable }} - you need to make them available trough the context.